# Questions with "do" vs. "do not" -- is "not" required?

Tags: meaning-in-context, questions, negation

I read an example of the term "ipso facto" in [Merriam Webster Dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ipso) which was:

> If we refuse to tolerate bigotry, do we become, ipso facto, as intolerant as those whom we condemn.

I think there should have been "not" after "do" in the example. I suppose that the example's speaker is asking this for a kind of confirmatiom, meaning that if we refuse to tolerate bigotry, then there remains no difference between us and them. Am I right?

Comment: This is also asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507843/shouldnt-there-be-not-before-do-in-this-example)

Comment: @Smock - different site: cannot close as a duplicate.

Comment: I know - just referencing so people can see the answer there too - not asking to close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example is grammatically correct as written.

These have the same basic meaning. Only the **shade** <sup>([Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shade#cald4-1-1-2))</sup> of meaning is different.

> Do I look good?
>
> Do I not look good?

The first one is understood as a more "neutral" question.

The second one is understood to mean that the person asking **believes the underlying statement is true:**  "I look good."

The same thing applies with questions written without "do":

> Am I being helpful?
>
> Am I not being helpful?

And

> Is he here?
>
> Is he not here?

They are functionally equivalent.  In a written essay (article), the word `"not"` is **optional**.  Since the dictionary is using an arbitrary example, you don't know if the speaker believes the **underlying statement** to be true, so it could be "do not" or "do": ***either is correct***.